# Self-study Order Statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

So I got this exercise from a book and I'm confused by a statement they made.

**Example:**
In a 100-meter Olympic race, the running times can be considered
to be $U$~$(9.6, 10.0)$-distributed. Suppose that there are eight competitors
in the finals. We wish to find the probability that the winner breaks the world
record of 9.69 seconds. All units are seconds.

---

**Solution**

We wish to
determine $P(X(1) < 9.69)$.

Since $f_X(x) = 2.5$ for $9.6 < x < 10.0$ and zero otherwise, **it follows that in**

**the interval $9.8 < x < 10.2$ we have $F_X(x) = 2.5x − 24$ and hence
$F_{X_{(1)}} (x) = 1 − (25 − 2.5x)^8$**

(since we assume that the running times are independent). Since the desired

probability equals $F_{X_{(1)}}(9.69)$, the answer to our problem is 
$1 − (25 − 2.5·9.69)^8  \approx 0.8699.$

---

*My question is that I don't see  why to look for the CDF on $9.8 < x < 10.2$ since that interval hasn't been mentioned in the question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo: they meant $9.6 < x < 10.0$. The CDF is still $F_X(x) = \frac{x - 9.6}{10.0-9.6} = 2.5 x - 24$.

Comment: Would you recommend me to delete the question or mention the name of the book so someone else doesn't get confused?